# Halacha of hair disposal

Tags: halacha, minhag, hair, disposal

Are there any traditions or halachic restrictions regarding the proper disposal of human hair (similar to with regard to nails or human remains)?

*Related*:

[According to Halacha, does one have to bury teeth?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10185/according-to-halacha-does-one-have-to-bury-teeth)

[Do surgically removed body parts require Kevurah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9909/do-surgically-removed-body-parts-require-kevurah)

[Moving nails better than burning them?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13884/moving-nails-better-than-burning-them)

[Traditions what to do with removed foreskin](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/22632/traditions-what-to-do-with-removed-foreskin/22633#22633)

[Rules for Cutting Nails](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1118/rules-for-cutting-nails)

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Sam's comment on an answer to [another MY question I just came across](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/53645/what-to-do-with-beard-hair-that-falls-out), Rav Elyashiv allows throwing out hair.